# Query to return a cursor containing only ids

Tags: mongodb, cursor

I'd like to get only the ids of a fairly large data set in mongo db (not breaking any records here, but too much to reasonably load into RAM).

I am currently using a cursor to iterate over all the ids in a collection, and working with the results that way. Is there a way to get just the ids (projection)? Would this be more efficient than just using the cursor over all records?

Comment: There is  [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsertFields) which is just returns an array of values. Depends if that is too large for your purpose though.

Comment: Do you mean _id or just a generic id field? Basically, wondering if you already have a unique constraint on the field, in which case all you need is a projection, otherwise you would need a distinct to avoid dupes.

Answer (score 1):

If the field is unique (and hence you have no issue with dupes), then yes, all you need to do is specify a projection.  For example, if you have a field named ID you would do something like this:

```
db.mycollection.find({}, {_id: 0, ID: 1})
```

That second argument to the find is the projection, and in this particular case we are asking for the query to return the `ID` field and specifically exclusing the _id field (which is always returned by default).

If you are storing these IDs in `_id`, then it becomes:

```
db.mycollection.find({}, {_id: 1})
```